# how to run only 1 function in a dictionary list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script in mind that would require an if statement with about 30+ elifs.
So I'm trying a dictionary method:

```
def a():
    print('a')
    return 'A is the number'

def b():
    print('b')
    return 'vvb is the number'

def c():
    print('c')
    return 'c is the number'

name = input('type it in: ')

list = {'a': a(), 'b': b(), 'c': c()}

if name in list:
    this = list[name]
    print(this)
else:
    print('name not in list')
```

In theory when I input `'a'`, it should return `"A is the number"`

But this is what I get:

```
type it in: a
a
b
c
A is the number
```

So obviously the list executed all the functions, and if I had 30+ large functions, it would slow things down considerably. Is there a way to only execute the function that is being called?

Or maybe there's a better way to do this?
    Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = {'a': a(), 'b': b(), 'c': c()}
```

Don't do that. What you wanted was this:

```
d = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}
```

Then, you'll want to *call* the function
once you know what `name` is:

```
this = d[name]()
```

Also, please don't use identifiers like `list` or `dir`
that are already defined as a [builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).
Much better to call it `d` for dict.
The `list()` function is very useful,
and you may soon find you need to call it,
perhaps even within the same function.
Calling a thing a "list" when it is not a list
will not help you to correctly reason about it.

Often an identifier along the lines of `name_to_fn[]`
will be appropriate for a dict mapping,
spelling out that in this case
it maps from name to function.

Comment: `list = ...`: don't do that, either.

Answer (score 1):

One option is remove the function calls from the `list` keys (also rename `list` to something other than a built-in python keyword, like `mylist`).

Then call the resulting function within the `print()` function:

```
mylist = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}

if name in mylist.keys():
    this = mylist[name]
    print(this())
```

result:

```
type it in: a
a
A is the number
```